# Motherboards which can handle 4 Gpu x16 Pcie

Tags: motherboard

I am looking for desktop motherboard which could handle:

- 4 x nvidia k4200 quadro (4 x PCIe x16, gen 3 if possible)
- Intel Core i7-4790
- 4 x DDR3 slot
- max. memory size 32 GB (at least)
- ATX format (if possible)

We would use them for cuda calculations we need full PCIe bandwith.
You can suggest other configuration which will cost not much to upgrade.

Also I wanted to know how it is possible to handle 4 gpu with x16 with one cpu. Will it be better than 2 gpu

Comment: Are you absolutely set on that CPU and socket? LGA2011-based configurations typically have more available PCI lanes.

Comment: we need configuration that will use full bandwidth but at the same time will cost not much to upgrade. CPU can be upgraded if there is no other choice. we currently stuck on Asus P9x79-e Ws

Comment: So, you're already on an LGA2011-based board. The upgrade of your current board is what I was thinking of, actually... Asus' X99-E WS (it's DDR4, though). If cost is a bigger factor than performance, you should edit that into your question.

Comment: we gonna to get asus p9x79-e. cause for now it seems best suit. only one cpu will be upgraded. So i posted this quesiton to get know if there is motherboard that could cost us without upgrade. x99-e  we have to buy rams too

Comment: Oh... Your comment made it sound like you were already using the P9X79-E WS. I recommend some edits to your question - you should discuss budget and what you're currently using, if anything.